# I am unable to upload attachment using SeleniumWebDriver

Tags: eclipse, testing, selenium-webdriver

This is my Code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Add_Photo_Browse0")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
StringSelection ss= new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\ns10\\Desktop\\download.jpg");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, ss);
Robot robo=new Robot();
robo.delay(1000);
robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

When I run the above code in Eclipse, it clicks on the File upload; then the windows pop up comes but doesn't select the file which I mentioned. It was just idle.

Could someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible try this first,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Add_Photo_Browse0")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\ns10\\Desktop\\download.jpg");
```

This is a noted way to upload file via selenium webdriver as of now, where you don't have to bother about clicking on the **File Upload** button and then using **Robot class** to upload image. Just sending the path of the file to upload will accomplish the **Upload**.

---

**If it still doesn't work**, then below is the alternative way by using **Robot and Sikuli (combined) to accomplish the task:-**

### **Problem:-**

Sometimes, the Robot class types the "attachment_path" into the "File Name" field of textbox but doesn't presses 'Enter key' thereafter for the file to upload.

### **Solution:-**

To avert that, I've used **Sikuli to click on the Open button**, which does infact uploads the file then;
**(Note:- You have to take a screenshot of [Open button](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dds1n1e849lffko/Open_file.png?dl=0) in the window's dialog box, that comes up after clicking on the "File Upload button".**

First of all download [sikuli-api standalone jar](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/downloads/detail?name=sikuli-api-1.0.2-standalone.jar&can=2&q=,). And, add it to the build path of your project. Then, add the below code for the file upload:-

```
    //Clicking on the File Upload button
 driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Add_Photo_Browse0")).click();

        //Copying the path of the file to the clipboard
        StringSelection attachment = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\ns10\\Desktop\\download.jpg"); //path to the attachment
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(attachment, null);

        //Pasting the contents of clipboard in the field "File name" of the Window Pop-up
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        try{
        ScreenRegion screen = new DesktopScreenRegion(); //screen is the default screen region which corresponds to the entire screen on your default monitor.
        Target target = new ImageTarget(new File("<PUT HERE THE PATH FOR THE OPEN BUTTON'S IMAGE>"));
        ScreenRegion screen_web = screen.wait(target,5000);
        screen_web = screen.find(target); //screen_web holds the screen region occupied by the "Open" button that was found by Sikuli's image recognition engine.

        if(screen_web != null)
        {
        Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse(); // Create a mouse object
        mouse.click(screen_web.getCenter()); // Use the mouse object to click on the center of the target region, i.e., the Open button
        }else{
        throw new Throwable();
        }
        }catch(Throwable e){
        System.err.println("The Open file button wasn't clicked!!" + e.getMessage() + "\n---------------------");
        }
```

---

**Code for Uploading in Tiny Pic.com :-**

```
package pack_ads;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.sikuli.api.DesktopScreenRegion;
import org.sikuli.api.ImageTarget;
import org.sikuli.api.ScreenRegion;
import org.sikuli.api.Target;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.Mouse;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopMouse;

public class Testing_TinyPicUpload {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();                                 //Opens a firefox browser instance
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        //Timeout of 30 seconds given
        driver.manage().window().maximize();                                    //Maximizing the window

        //Navigating to tiny pic site
        driver.get("http://tinypic.com/");


        //Uploading photo
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='the_file']")).click();        //Locating the attach button

        //Copying the path of the file to the clipboard     
        StringSelection photo = new StringSelection("D:\\\\Images\\default.jpg"); //Putting the path of the image to upload
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(photo, null);

        //Pasting the contents of clipboard in the field "File name" of the Window Pop-up

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        try{
            ScreenRegion screen = new DesktopScreenRegion();    //screen is the default screen region which corresponds to the entire screen on your default monitor. 
            Target target = new ImageTarget(new File("Tinyimages\\Open_file.png")); //Made a folder in my project as Tinyimages and put the image of Open_file in there.
            ScreenRegion screen_web = screen.wait(target,5000);
            screen_web = screen.find(target);   //screen_web holds the screen region occupied by the "Open" button that was found by Sikuli's image recognition engine. 

            if(screen_web != null)
            {
                Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse(); // Create a mouse object
                mouse.click(screen_web.getCenter());     // Use the mouse object to click on the center of the target region, i.e., the Open button
            }
            else{
                throw new Throwable();
            }
            System.out.println("Attachment was successfully done.\n------------------------------\n");
        }catch(Throwable e){
            System.err.println("The Open file button wasn't clicked!!" + e.getMessage() + "\n------------------------------");
        }



    }

}
```

Note: You can download use this image for the "Open" button from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dds1n1e849lffko/Open_file.png?dl=0). Change the file path accordingly in the code `Target target = new ImageTarget(new File("Tinyimages\\Open_file.png"));`

Comment: Thanks for your code .......but the path is  not getting pasted on the clipboard. it remains the same

Comment: @Saravana : You mean, the path is not getting pasted in the field **"File name"** of the opened Window Dialog Box?

Comment: @Saravana: It seems to work when I tried to upload a file using the exact same code(for different webpage). Are you getting any issue or something?

Comment: i don't get any error.. 'File Upload' pop-up opens and remain s idle. could you try this site http://tinypic.com/ and tell me. whether the 'Choose File' uploads the pics or not

Comment: @Saravana: Yes it does. Just add `Thread.sleep(5000);` before `Robot robot = new Robot();`. It should definitely work. **Probably, more time was needed for getting the focus to the window dialog button, that's why the paste of clipboard contents wasn't happening.** _If you want, I will update the code for uploading in [tinypic.com](http://tinypic.com) too.._ Please let me know, how it goes.

Comment: @Saravana: I have added the code for Tiny pic image upload above.. Please check and let me know

Comment: could you please send me the complete code of tinypic.com

Comment: i will verify and let you know

Comment: the same code i run...the same thing happens. 'File Upload' pop-up opens doesn't paste anything in the File Name field.

Comment: why we have to create a new folder & what is this code for  ImageTarget(new File("Tinyimages\\Open_file.png"));

Comment: It's not mandatory to create a new folder. You can just download the image, put the image wherever you want, just paste the path there inside `new File("<path>")`. It was for a little convenience that I put it up there.  And, this image is the base image for Sikuli to match in the UI, and hence proceed with clicking on it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65190/discussion-between-subh-and-saravana).

Comment: @Saravana: 
This is the video link for the execution of tiny image upload.
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/uj4248rcu6rva4h/TinyPicImageUpload.mp4?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uj4248rcu6rva4h/TinyPicImageUpload.mp4?dl=0)
The code works..
And, regarding this **'File Upload' pop-up opens doesn't paste anything in the File Name field.**, Give it some time, as I've given 5 seconds of sleep time there. After that it will paste the path in the field. If you are still facing issue, please open the chat link above to discuss with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was finding the same result, that the code would halt and wait when the File Upload window was opened, and would only continue after the window was closed.
As a workaround I put the thread sleep and the robot keypresses in a separate thread that I spawned just before clicking the file upload button. This solved the issue for me.

// Thread class to be instantiated and run just before button click:
//

public class PasteUploadFileThread extends Thread {

```
  String uploadFileName = "";

  public PasteUploadFileThread(String filename){
      this.uploadFileName = filename;
  }

public void run() {
    try {
        // Pause 3 seconds giving window time to open up
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        System.out.println("STARTING PasteUploadFileThread for file: " + this.uploadFileName);

        StringSelection ss= new StringSelection(this.uploadFileName);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, ss);

        Robot robo=new Robot();
        robo.delay(2000);
        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robo.delay(2000);
        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        System.out.println("ENDING PasteUploadFileThread for file: " + this.uploadFileName);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

// Portion of the test class that spawns the thread and then clicks the button

```
    String filepath = "C:\\UploadDocument.txt";    

    WebElement browseButton = wait60Secs.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Browse')]")));

    // Spawn a thread that will do the interacting with the File Upload window.
    // This is needed because when we click on the browse button the code halts waiting for the File Upload window to be closed.
    // So this thread will go off on it's own and do it's work while this code is paused.
    (new PasteUploadFileThread(filepath)).start();

    browseButton.click();

    // Execution continues here after the Upload window is closed...
    // Find the file that was uploaded before continuing
    wait60Secs.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'UploadDocument.txt')]")));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  If you show the code you used to solve the problem, it will improve your answer, and save anyone the trouble of researching how to implement your workaround :)